# tkinter Checkbutton default value and data returned

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter.checkbutton

I use tkinter Checkbutton to get the information needed and my scripts are:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilenames

window = Tk()
window.title('File Viewer')
frm=Frame(window)

filelist=[]

def selectfiles():
    files=askopenfilenames(initialdir="D:\\Document", title="Select files")
    fileList = window.tk.splitlist(files)
    filelist.append(fileList)

btn = Button(frm,text='Select Files',command=selectfiles)
frm.pack()
btn.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)

Heads = {'Head A': "HeadAEPTrend1 (Float)", 'Head B': "HeadBEPTrend1 (Float)"}
head_list=[]
for (key, value) in Heads.items():
    strVar = StringVar()
    head_list.append(strVar)
    cb = Checkbutton(frm, text=key, variable=strVar, onvalue=value, offvalue='NA')
    cb.pack(anchor=W)
parameters=[strvar.get() for strvar in head_list if strvar.get() != 'NA']

window.mainloop()
```

There are 2 things I did not expected:

1. In the GUI the default is both head A and head B are selected.(I want the default is both heads not selected)
2. I can only get `['','']` when I call `parameters` in the shell after I closed the GUI.

Anyone knows what's going wrong?

Comment: The Checkbutton's variable needs to be given a value that matches either its `onvalue` or its `offvalue` for it to work right.  And `parameters` was set *once*, prior to the mainloop; it will reflect the variable values at that moment in time only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: Add `value='NA'` when you initiate your `StringVar`.

```
for (key, value) in Heads.items():
    strVar = StringVar(value='NA')
    ...
```

2: Consider this:

```
head_list=[]
...
parameters=[strvar.get() for strvar in head_list if strvar.get() != 'NA']
...
```

There is no selection when your list comprehension of `parameters` is done. You need to do it after the checkbuttons have been clicked, no before. You can do so by adding a command to your `Checkbutton`, or trace changes on your `StringVar`. e.g.:

```
def get_parameters():
    global parameters
    parameters=[strvar.get() for strvar in head_list if strvar.get() != 'NA']

...

for (key, value) in Heads.items():
    ...
    cb = Checkbutton(frm, text=key, variable=strVar, onvalue=value, offvalue='NA',
                     command=get_parameters)
...
```